# How to Create .wgetrc format file in Linux

Tags: linux

Hi anyone knows how to create .wgetrc file on Linux? I want to add user credentials in this file for building Yocto image purpose. Any helps will be very appreciated.

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[Here’s](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Sample-Wgetrc.html) a sample .wgetrc file and [here’s](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html) some documentation on the possible values you can set in it. The file should exist in `$HOME/.wgetrc`, you can use any text editor to create and edit it.